# Lower bound on a bilinear quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, upper-lower-bounds

Does the inequality
$$x^T A y \ge \lambda_{\text{min}}(A) \|x\|\|y\|$$
hold assuming that $A$ is positive semidefinite?

Edit:
I am stuck here:
Diagonalizing $A=UDU^T$ and letting $d_i,j$ denote the $i,j^{th}$ entry of $D$, then
$$x^TAy=x^TUDU^Ty\\
=\sum_{i,j}[U^Tx]_i[U^Ty]_jd_{i,j}\\
=\sum_i[U^Tx]_i[U^Ty]_id_{i,i}$$

Comment: Have you made any progress yourself on that question?

Comment: @Meowdog Yes, added it.

Comment: Give the assumptions! Viewing the second part, I guess that the matrix $A$ is assumed to be  symmetric with values in $\mathbb{R}$. This should be said. When $A$ is semi-definite positive and non null, the inequality cannot hold for every $x$ ad $y$, since the left hand side can be negative, wehreas the right-hand side is always non-negative.

Comment: Take $A=I$ and $y=-x\neq 0.$ Then $x^TAy=-\|x\|^2$ and $\lambda_{\rm min}(A)=1.$

Answer (score 1):

It is not even true that $|x^TAy| \geq \lambda_{\min}(A)\|x\|\|y\|$. As an example, take
$$
A = \pmatrix{2&0\\0&1}, \quad x = \pmatrix{1\\1}, \quad y = \pmatrix{-1\\2}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

It's never true with absolute value as long as $A$ is invertible, i.e. $\lambda_{\min}>0.$ For any $y\neq 0$ there exists $x\neq 0$ such that $Ay\perp x.$ Then $x^TAy=0$ but $\lambda_\min|x\|\,\|y\|>0.$ I assume the dimension is at least $2.$